# MySQL query filtering results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named pt_products with the fields:

```
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ean` bigint(13) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `merchant` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2)NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Example of entries on the table:

```
INSERT INTO `pt_products` (`id`, `ean`, `merchant`, `price`) VALUES
 ('1', '884116311874', 'Amazon', '10000.00'),
  ('2', '884116311874', 'BestBuy', '10999.00'),
('3','884116321378', 'CyberPuerta', '14789.00'),
 ('4', '884116311875', 'Amazon', '10999.00'),
  ('5', '884116311875', 'BestBuy', '10000.00');
```

What I need to do is:

-Group the entries on the table that have the same ean.

-Discard the grouped entries in case none of them have "Amazon" on the `merchant` field.

-Discard the grouped entries that have "Amazon" on the `merchant` field if the `price` field of the one containing "Amazon" as merchant has not the lowest `price` field.

-At least one different merchant with the same 'ean' besides 'Amazon'

What I have achieved is to group the entries of the table by ean, but this displays all the entries ordered by ean:

```
SELECT ean, merchant, price FROM pt_products ORDER BY ean;
```

I wonter what is the best way to get the desired results. If by using the apprpiate query of by filtering the results from the query using a php loop.

You can test using the example I given above [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=0Ab9rIl4gu)
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by `ean` and set the condition in the having clause:

```
SELECT ean
FROM pt_products
GROUP BY ean
HAVING MIN(price) = MIN(CASE WHEN merchant = 'Amazon' THEN price END)
   AND SUM(merchant <> 'Amazon') > 0
```

If you want all the rows for the results of the above query, then use also the operator `IN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pt_products
WHERE ean IN (
    SELECT ean
    FROM pt_products
    GROUP BY ean
    HAVING MIN(price) = MIN(CASE WHEN merchant = 'Amazon' THEN price END) 
       AND SUM(merchant <> 'Amazon') > 0
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=e6ca21676a5ae553b443fc830f92cb29).
Results:

```
>    id |          ean | merchant    |    price
> ----: | -----------: | :---------- | -------:
>     1 | 884116311874 | Amazon      | 10000.00
>     2 | 884116311874 | BestBuy     | 10999.00
> 87448 |  10343943704 | Amazon      |  3259.00
> 93885 |  10343943704 | Linio       |  3999.00
> 94913 |  10343943704 | XtremeTecPc |  3834.00
```

Comment: That is a nice aproach. The problem with that query is that it also displays the entires where only Amazon has that ean. 
The desired result is to display those where 'Amazon' merchant has the lowest price where there is at least one different merchant with the same 'ean'.

Check this example. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=dd5cf4d962ba7ff2eee7f6fa22266677

The entry
```
('94919', '10343943708','Amazon', '9999.99')
```
Should not be displayed, since only Amazon has that ean.

Comment: Did you mention this condition: *at least one different merchant with the same 'ean'* in your question?

Comment: Sorry:( Looks like I thought I did, but I did not. I will edit it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks.  What if after all the previous filtering, I  want to just display the merchant  "Amazon" ?

Requeriments would be:

-Group the entries on the table that have the same ean.

-Discard the grouped entries in case none of them have "Amazon" on the merchant field.
-Discard the grouped entries that have "Amazon" on the merchant field if the price field of the one containing "Amazon" as merchant has not the lowest price field.
-At least one different merchant with the same 'ean' besides 'Amazon'
-Of the result, display only the entries that have Amazon as merchant

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=6767fa02f3db2fac053d4c7428b5428c